# Доменный объект в контроллере, как правильно использовать?

Tags: ооп, проектирование

Я не могу найти ответа на следующий вопрос:
У меня есть контроллер, туда приходят запросы от представления, контроллер запускает какой то сценарий. Например в слое домена создаётся новый заказ и принимает какие то дефолтные значения. Как мне это пробросить в представление? Проблема в том, что контроллер не может перескочить через слой сценариев и обработать доменный объект с заказом. DTOшку тоже стремно гонять, придётся поля дублировать, и в конце концов я буду забывать добавлять поля.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно поступают в таких случаях.

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален? Вопрос касается только, скажем, Андроид, или не обязательно какой-то конкретной технологии? Если не только конкретной технологии, то поясните, про сценарии. Не понятна фраза: "контроллер не может перескочить через слой сценариев". Возможно, вопрос будет понятнее, если его более развернуто изложить.

Comment: Вопрос актуален. Имеется ввиду многослойная архитектура.

Comment: [Эта](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2011/11/android-architecture-part-1-intro/) статья поможет? Там, контроллер посылает сообщения. Это не единственный вариант, как можно организовать. Прошу прощения если не в тему. Если что, то сотру это сообщение.